# Best way to handle offline and online development with Git

Tags: git, version-control, github

Maybe the title didn't exactly convey my problem, but a little explanation will be enough. I have this situation where I'm developing a website with another friend, and we're using Git to manage the versioning of the code, etc.

Problem is, at home (for both of us) is all good, we sync, then we submit changes and commit. But at work (and we work at the same company) our firewall blocks Git and sometimes we are able to get something done here, but without being able to retrieve or push updates to Git, how do we keep everything synched withtout Git going crazy?

After a few attempts at this, by simply copying everything to a pendrive and then try to sync it all at home, and screwing everything, finally managed something that "kinda works", which is by using xcopy with "newer files" only option. But even that sometimes messes things up.

Anyone ever come up a similar situation? Any ideas for me? Thanks.

Comment: Is the project you're working on for work, or outside of work?  Can you ask your company to host something for this or not?

Comment: Outside of work. Can't really ask them to open a firewall rule for me.

Comment: Two words for you: ssh tunnel.

Comment: If you work at the same company, do you have a common shared directory you both can access? Or is it possible for one to have a shared folder, and have the other access it? If that’s the case, you could just make a second remote repository which you use while at work, and every day when you get home, you additionally push the new version to your regular repository.

Answer (score 3):

Using a pen-drive could work, but not the way you use it.

What you need is to treat the pen-drive as a remote. So basically you make a bare repository on the pen-drive and push-pull from it. Git will then manage everything.

In short, something like this:

```
# make repository in pen-drive:
$ cd /path/to/pen/drive
$ mkdir repo; cd repo; git init --bare
```

And in your repositories (both at home and work):

```
$ git remote add pendrive /path/to/pen/drive/repo
```

You can then start pushing to/pulling from `pendrive` the same way you would do any other remote.

Still, more appropriate would be to ask your company to not block ssh to GitHub (Unless you shouldn't be doing these stuff at work, in which case, well don't do them at work).

Comment: Well, you're correct, I shouldn't. :)
But what if my repository is also my working dir (htdocs in Apache, in this case), how could I use the pendrive?

Comment: @ChristianDechery, I don't understand what you mean by "working dir" and how that changes anything. If the directory you code in is under `git`, then you can do any `git` operations on it. You use the pendrive the same way you use `github` (assuming it's `origin`). If you can do `git push origin master` (but blocked by firewall), then you can also do `git push pendrive master`. The only difference is that `github` has an address like `git@github.com:User/Repo` and `pendrive` has an address like `/media/your_pen_drive_name/path/to/repo` for example. They are both handled by git equally.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. At some point I will need to sync everything with github. How would I achieve that if I'm now using my pendrive as the place I'm pushing the updates to? When I get home (where I have access) how do I sync the contents of the pendrive with my local repo at home, and then with github.com?

Comment: @ChristianDechery, git is a distributed version control system. you can have many remotes, push to any you want and pull from any you want. so basically you can do (at home for example): `git pull pendrive` to get changes from the pendrive, then do `git push origin` to push to new stuff to github

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to get this, hope you can understand I'm kinda of noob to git (you already know that, I'm sure). Since I will be pushing to pendrive, I first need to populate it (clone?) with all my code, right? So I downloaded the zip from github (only way I can access it). How can start all with a clean slate, all synched to what I have on github.com - both the local repo and pendrive, assuming I will start now to make changes? Only after that, I think, I can start working on my local repo and pushing to pendrive, right?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you work on your pen drive ? You can now find afordable yet durable pendrive, or even SSD with USB port on them.

Put your Git folder on it, backup it sometime on a classic hard drive. And you're done.